# Free distributed wiki software with full-text search, working even offline

Tags: collaboration, offline, document-management, wiki, distributed

I'm looking for a way to organize knowledge in my company.
Since we have to work disconnected from the company net many times, a server-client solution alone won't suffice.

The requirements are:

- distributed, i.e. can be used while not connected to any server
- mergeable, i.e. changes made on two copies should be mergable
- full-text searchable, even in attached documents (plain text, word, excel, pdf)
- should be easy to use, even for non-programmers
- contents should be taggable, i.e. a single folder like structure won't suffice

Open source would be great, a reasonable fee would be also fine.

Simply said, I'm looking for a wiki (or something comparable), that has a backend which can be managed by git or another dvcs and whose artifacts (indices etc.) can be easily updated/rebuild.

So far I found [IkiWiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ikiwiki) which is a wiki that supports git, but it seems to lack full text search in attached doc, pdf or excel files.

UPDATE:
Best hit so far seems [FosWiki](http://foswiki.org/), which seams to meet most requirements. I'll update the question after further investigation.

Comment: Do you need all features to work even when offline? For instance tags and attached document search.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul These are vital requirements. Some colleagues spend most time out of office. And non-searchable documents are much less valuable. Also when someone adds content while not connected, it should need no post-processing when connected again.

Comment: What speaks against using command-line tools like grep and [application specific grep-alikes](http://noone.org/blog/English/Computer/Shell/grep%20everything.futile) on the local copies? (After reading all the dotted items I planned to write an answer recommending Ikiwiki. Then I read that Ikiwiki already has been found and -- to my surprise -- wasn't sufficient.)

Comment: @xtaran: The users are not programmers, so command line is no option. Using git will be hard enough to teach...

Comment: @AxelBeckert What about [ack](http://beyondgrep.com/)? - As frontend [gollum](https://github.com/gollum/gollum) is not that bad, but full text search still missing.

Comment: @koppor: `ack` is not the fastest (use it's C-written pendant `ag` aka Silversearcher instead if performance is an issue) and its output not meant for being parsed by other tools but optimised for being read by humans. So it IMHO is not suitable as backend for a CGI script (or similar) searching through all the contents of a wiki.